# Laravel integrity constraint violation when saving many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When storing a new user and then `syncing` some many to many relationships I get an integrity constraint error as the ID of the newly created user seems to not be passed to the `sync()` method. Here is my `store` controller method:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Input::get('password');
$user->save();

// See if roles are passed, if not assign the default role of "view_site"
$roles = Input::has('roles') ? Input::get('roles') : [3];
$user->roles()->sync($roles);
```

As you can see I call `save()` before trying to `sync` the related data so it should have an ID. Here is the error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null
>   (SQL: insert into `users_roles` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (3, ))

If I run the sync method on an already existent user (`User::find($id)->roles()->sync([1,2,3])`) it works fine.

For reference, the relationships:

```
// User.php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'users_roles');
}
// Role.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_roles');
}
```

**Edit:**

Query log prior to the `sync()`. Looks like the `save()` is not writing to the database...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [time] => 0.63
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select `roles`.*, `users_roles`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `users_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `users_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` where `users_roles`.`user_id` = ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [time] => 0.58
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [query] => select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ? or `username` = ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test@example.com
                    [1] => example
                )

            [time] => 0.48
        )

)
```

Comment: Just for debugging : if you execute `User::find($validId)->roles()->sync($roles);`, you will get the same error ?

Comment: No, that works flawlessly

Comment: Maybe you are using `Ardent` (auto validation when saving), so when you call `$user->save();` nothing happen. Any way, please add `var_dump('DB::getQueryLog()')` at the end, and share the results

Comment: I am using confide, but not ardant. I will get the query log and post above

Comment: make sense, because Field/model validation is powered by `Ardent`, you have two choice : recheck your validation, or use `->forceSave()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide), the validation is based on [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent).
In your `store` method, add `if` statement

```
if($user->save());
    $roles = Input::has('roles') ? Input::get('roles') : [3];
    $user->roles()->sync($roles);
}else{
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($user->errors());
}
```

If you don't need to check validation , you may use

```
$user->forceSave();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It appears it is a validation error. I run the validator before anyway using `if ( Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules)->passes() )` and it appears to pass. However, there does seem to be a password confirmation mismatch evident from adding your code. I include the `password_confirmation` input in my form.

Comment: Do I need to do `$user->password_confirmation = Input::get('password_confirmation');` too for Ardent to check it?

Comment: Seems you need to add it. Please show your `$rules`

Comment: Yes, my rules do contain a `confirmed` for the password. The issue was ardent as you said. Have removed the normal laravel validation and it now works as it should. Thanks.